# Empty string after passing through the function

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I got an empty string on the first element of the array ("") while the others are correct. It seems that the string object is destroyed right after exiting the function. Is it not related to Dangling pointer?
How to solve it?

```
void func(const char**&ptr)
{
    std::string errorstring = "Test1";
    ptr = (const char **)malloc(5 * sizeof(const char *));
    ptr[0] = errorstring.c_str();
    ptr[1] = "Test2";
    ptr[2] = "Test3";
    ptr[3] = "Test4";
    ptr[4] = "Test5";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. It sure is, 3. Do something else. Modern C++ code does not need to malloc or new anything. Focus on getting rid of whatever reason you think you need to malloc or new something.

Comment: *Is it not related to Dangling pointer?* Yes - that's exactly what you are assigning to `ptr[0]` - a dangling pointer.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` -- That is what you use in modern C++, not triple pointers.

Comment: Thanks PaulMcKenzie. I will try this strategy. It seems that I did not get upgraded yet to the new unmanaged functions. Usually, I used to be on the managed ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr[0]` is set to point to a buffer managed by `errorstring`. When the function returns, `errorstring` goes out of scope and is destroyed, deallocating that buffer. `ptr[0]` becomes a dangling pointer. Any attempt by the caller to dereference it would exhibit undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `"Text1"`, a char array will be allocated somewhere.
When you type `std::string errorstring = "Test1";`, then `errorstring` will be initialised with this array, it will not just reference it, it will copy the entire array of characters - `"Text1"` into its own memory. At the end of `func`, the destructor of `errorstring` will be called automatically, and it will free its own memory, rendering whatever `.c_str()` returned invalid. As such, `ptr[0]` becomes a *dangling pointer*. The misconception would be that `errorstring` is the same as (simply a reference to) "Test1", because of the `=` sign. But `=` in c++ means assignment, not equality. Infact, `errorstring` is an entirely different object than `"Test1"`.